# Matching "$" using regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

i am trying to write a regular expression for matching any words like which come in between "$" 
for example 
var myString  = " there was a $dog$# and a $rat$ in a town";
i want to match dog and rat
i have written the expresion for it

```
       var reg = /^$(.*)$/gmi
```

but that does not because , the "$" being special character of end of line , how can i escape it , can i use "\" ?? 
can you pelase suggest the correct expression .

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters

Comment: So, what happened when you tried `\\`, which is the correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said you should use '\' to escape the special characters. Also '^' is the start of the string you want to match for.
You should use the following:

```
/\$(.*)\$/g
```

Comment: @matov , if i use /\$(.*)\$/gmi in the string  "there is a '$game$' which talks about the game and a $dog$$" it will return the whole thing from game......dog

Comment: What are `m` and `i` for in this case?

Comment: @m.buettner: `m` makes sense if you have `"...$do\ng$..."` (which doesn't make too much sense, but I don't know OP's data). `i` is useless.

Comment: You mean "s" instead of "m" ;). "m" makes ^ and $ match the start and end of lines.

Comment: yeah, right, soz... just copied and pasted the gmi bit. Early hours in Europe:)

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with greediness, as you mentioned in a few comments. `*` will consume as much as possible, so if it is used like `.*` it will also consume further `$` if it can find another one later one. There are two possibilities. The quickest and most common one is to simply make that quantifier ungreedy:

```
/\$(.*?)\$/g
```

Now it will consume as little as possible. The recommended way however is to make the repetition and the delimiter mutually exclusive and keep the repetition greedy:

```
/\$([^$]*)\$/g
```

This is generally more efficient, because no backtracking is needed. (Please don't hold me up on that, in any specific case the backtracking version might still be more efficient, but this is generally recommended practice)

Answer (score 1):

```
/\$(.*)\$/
```

You use `\` for escaping, as you thought. Also, given your requirements, `^` (start of string) is detrimental.

In case you have multiple appearances of such strings, you have to be careful of greediness (the default), so you either disallow the terminator from the contents:

```
/\$([^$]*)\$/g
```

or you make the repetition operator non-greedy:

```
/\$(.*?)\$/g
```

Comment: can you look at the comment i made to matov's post

Comment: Yup. Clarified; I didn't notice your modifiers.

Comment: @m.buettner: lol, not a competition... (despite the page keeping the score :p )

Comment: Sure, my comment wasn't meant to be taken too serious ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, escaping is done with `\` -s, if you want to catch individual `$...$` marked words try this regexp:

```
/\$([^$]+)\$/gmi // inside character classes ( the []-s) you don't need to escape it, but if you do it does the same thing
```

Answer (score 0):

> can i use "\" ??

Yes.

Why didn't you try that yourself?

```
var reg = /^\$(.*)\$/gmi
```

will match:

- Start of string
- A `$`
- Zero of more characters
- A `$`